Get Bech32 (Native SegWit) Bitcoin Address From The Public Key (ec_compressed) Using libbitcoin-system 3.8.0
How can I get the Bech32 (Native SegWit) Bitcoin Address from the ec_private without using HD Keys. My code is as follows and I am quite struggling to use libbitcoin documentation.
#include <bitcoin/system.hpp>

using namespace bc;
using namespace std;
using namespace wallet;

int main()
{
    data_chunk seed(16);
    pseudo_random_fill(seed);

    ec_secret secretKey = bitcoin_hash(seed);
    ec_private wif(secretKey, 0x8000, true);

    ec_compressed publicKey = wif.to_public().point();
   // How to get the Bech32 (Native SegWit) address?
    ...

    return 0;
}


If you write it manually, you can obtain a Bech32 address.
    // How to get the Bech32 (Native SegWit) address?
    libbitcoin::short_hash witness_program = libbitcoin::bitcoin_short_hash(publicKey);
    libbitcoin::data_chunk script;
    script.insert(script.end(), witness_program.begin(), witness_program.end());
    auto data = convert_bits(script, 8, 5);
    data.insert(data.begin(), 0x00);

    std::string hrp = "bc";
    std::vector<uint8_t> checksum = bech32_create_checksum(hrp, data);
    data.insert(data.end(), checksum.begin(), checksum.end());

    std::string address = bech32_encode(hrp, data);

